# In Catholic teaching, to what scripture is each of the seven sacraments referenced?

Tags: catholicism, biblical-basis, sacraments

In Catholic teaching, to what scripture (OT and NT) is each of the [seven sacraments](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ccc_css/archive/catechism/p2s2.htm) referenced?

The seven sacraments are:

1. Baptism,
2. Confirmation (or Chrismation),
3. the Eucharist,
4. Penance,
5. the Anointing of the Sick,
6. Holy Orders and
7. Matrimony.

Comment: Here: http://catholic-resources.org/ChurchDocs/Sacraments.htm

Comment: @Reluctant_Linux_User Very nice! Put it in an answer so that you may share and get due credit.

Comment: Are you looking for scriptural support for why each sacrament is needed, how they should be performed, or general evidence that it was done in biblical times?

Comment: @JustinY You have answered. Thank you! I am just awarding you an additional bounty (in about 24 hours) for your efforts.

Comment: @FMS Thanks. I certainly didn't expect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summarized from http://catholic-resources.org/ChurchDocs/Sacraments.htm as pointed out by [Reluctant_Linux_User](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/34562/in-catholic-teaching-to-what-scripture-is-each-of-the-seven-sacraments-referenc/36399#comment92507_34562):

1. **Baptism** -  [Mathew 28:19](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matt%2028%3A19&version=NABRE) - "Go, therefore, and make disciples of all nations, baptizing them in the name of the Father, and of the Son, and of the holy Spirit"
2. **Confirmation** - [Acts 8:17; 19:6](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts%208%3A17%3B%2019%3A6&version=NABRE) - "Then they laid hands on them and they received the holy Spirit."
3. **Eucharist** - [Luke 22:14-20](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%2022%3A14-20&version=NABRE) - The Last Supper
4. **Penance**<sup>1</sup> - [James 5:16](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=James%205%3A16&version=NABRE) - "Therefore, confess your sins to one another"
5. **Anointing of the Sick** - [James 5:14](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=James%205%3A14&version=NABRE) - "Is anyone among you sick? He should summon the presbyters of the church, and they should pray over him and anoint [him] with oil in the name of the Lord"
6. **Holy Orders** -  [Acts 6:6](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts%206%3A6&version=NABRE) - "They presented these men to the apostles who prayed and laid hands on them."
7. **Matrimony** - [Genesis 2:24](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Gen%202%3A24&version=NABRE) - "That is why a man leaves his father and mother and clings to his wife, and the two of them become one body."

I suggest reading the article linked about for more scriptural support and more information about how and why they are performed.

---

<sup>1. cf. [**Penny Catechism Q.283.**](http://www.catholictreasury.info/catechism/cat23.php) *When did our Lord institute the Sacrament of Penance?* **A.** Our Lord instituted the Sacrament of Penance when he breathed on his Apostles and gave them power to forgive sins, saying: 'Whose sins you shall forgive, they are forgiven.' [John 20:23](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%2020%3A23&version=RSVCE)</sup>